# How to add a. [[inputs.exec]] plugin written in python to Telegraf?

Tags: grafana, influxdb, telegraf-inputs-plugin

I have Telegraf, Influxdb and Grafana installed. I was asked to write code to collect some metrics and make new dashboards with them. My script makes outputs in the form: Measurement, tag=value tag=value. Just one line at a time.

I added the script as a plugin to Telegraf but it won't show up in Grafana when I try to make a new dashboard. What could I be missing?

Comment: Could you please share the detailed logs or screenshots here? This would make it easier for others to answer your question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

My bad, the output format was wrong.
It's Measurement,field tag=value

Sorry if I didn't use the correct terms, but I hope everyone understands what I mean.